# Why are my USB 2.0 ports stuck in low-speed 1.0 mode?

Tags: usb, performance

My usb ports are stuck in 1.0 mode, i cant get them to work in 2.0 mode to get my devices to work. i tried a fresh install and rebootng many times, the mouse is slow and jumpy and transfers take a while.

Comment: Probably it's forced in your computer's BIOS settings.

Comment: everything works fine when i boot in windows, only have the issue in ubuntu, using 12.04, tried older versions and a few fresh installs and reboots

Comment: Have you tried different usb ports?

Comment: Please share the output of the `dmesg` command ([instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612))

Comment: What did you use the test USB with?

Answer (score 0):

disable legacy usb from the bios and if you dont have usb 3 also disable backwards compatibility mode in the usb settings in bios.