# Why has hibernation stopped working after moving my 12.04 install to a different laptop?

Tags: hibernate

I recently got a new laptop (Thinkpad X230). I didn't really have time to do a fresh install so I copied my install (xubuntu 12.04) over from my old machine (Thinkpad X61). Now when I try to hibernate it seems to do the Hibernate step fine, but doesn't seem to try and resume when booting back up. It just does a fresh boot. Is there something I need to do so the system knows where to look for the hibernation data?

/var/log/boot.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1056101/

dmesg: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1056102/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please share the output of the following files and/or commands with us [using the instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command `dmesg` , file `/var/log/boot.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the pointer to /var/log/boot.log, I noticed the line

```
swapon: /dev/sda5: software suspend data detected. Rewriting the swap signature.
```

Some googling around that lead me to [bug 499940](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/499940), which gave me the name of the file that controls where to look for the resume data, `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`. This file still had my old swap partition UUID in it. Updating that info and running `sudo update-initramfs -u` solved the issue and hibernate now works.

I was wondering if there was an official way to update this file/data and found a Debian bug (#[565225](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=565225)) around the issue, but it has no resolution. Hand editing `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` seems to be the only solution other than perhaps something involving adding/removing the initramfs-tools package, since the file is created by the postinstall hooks.