# Why doesn't bluetooth work on my Sony Vaio?

Tags: helpfile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my Sony VIAO to connect to Bluetooth devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166959/how-do-i-get-my-sony-viao-to-connect-to-bluetooth-devices)

specifications:
Platform 2nd generation Intel® Core™ i5 processor

Chipset Intel® HM65 Express Chipset

CPU Intel® Core™ i5-2430M Processor

Graphic Card Name Intel® HD Graphics 3000

WIFI Atheros 9285

Comment: post result of `lspci` and `rfkill list all`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As Web-E requested, please share the output of the following files and/or commands with us [(instructions in this answer)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): commands `sudo lspci`, `sudo lshw`, `dmesg` `rfkill list all` and file `/var/log/kern.log`