# ubuntu issue with lock screen

Tags: 12.04, unity

I have locked my screen with<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> Then login window appears.

After some time, it goes away, and the screen goes black. So far, so good. The problem is that after a while it shows the window login again, as though the mouse had been touched for example.

That is however not the case. What's wrong ??

Comment: Is your mouse a wireless one?  Do you have a trackpad, or a trackstick in your keyboard?  Is this system a laptop?

Comment: No it's wired. No trackpad or trackstick in my keyboard. No it's not a laptop

Comment: **What brand/model of mouse?  Is it USB?**  I have experienced this issue, some time ago, with an overly sensitive mouse.  I swapped it out, instead of attempting to resolve.

Comment: It's a good mouse (mx518 logitech) so i doubt it's where the problem comes from, besides it doesnt do that on my other os, xp

Comment: Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file `/var/log/kern.log`, command `dmesg`

Comment: This unanswered question about Ubuntu 12.04 (EOL) is 5+ years old. OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years. VTC as `not reproducible`.