# Why does my Ubuntu freeze in the middle of something with a blank screen?

Tags: 12.04, dell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I am facing a serious problem as my Dell Optiplex 745 loaded with Ubuntu 12.04 32bit freezes with a blank screen no mouse cursor no keyboard activity in many occasions.

Sometimes when I open firefox, or software center, I really can't tell what the main problem is, but what i am certain about is it i have to do a hard reset to reboot.

I tried to use a live-cd to boot but it did the same, tried the recovery console but couldn't find a way to fix from there (I am a new user) suspected a hardware problem but windows runs flawlessly so I believe its something related to ubuntu.

**Specs:**
Intel Celeron D 3.06 GHZ
3.0 GB ram
Intel built in graphics Q965
1 TB HDD
Bios Phoenex 2.6.4

Please help I really love ubuntu and I don't want to go back to windows!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please share the output of the following files and/or commands with us to help you troubleshoot your problem  [(**instructions** in this answer)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command `dmesg`, file `/var/log/kern.log`

Comment: mate now i cant even access my system without a freeze !