# Boot time seems unusually long on MSI GX660R (bootchart included)

Tags: boot

After upgrading (clean install) to Ubuntu 12.04, the speed issue when running programs has reduced on my MSI GX660R laptop. However, the boot time is still much longer (over a minute, even after BIOS) than on the many less powerful laptops I have encountered running the same OS, and I was wondering if anyone could help me improve it.

I use the FGLRX driver, if that makes any difference.

I have uploaded a boot chart, it can be found here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/bootchartl.png/

As you can see, the boot time is over a minute even after BIOS. A 'designed for Vista' laptop from ages ago which I installed Ubuntu on boots in around thirty seconds, so I think it's a bit strange.

---

Output of dmesg: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1081359/

Output of /var/log/kern.log : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1081363/

Output of /var/log/syslog : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1081365/

Comment: Boot charts look nice, but are harder for old Linux guys to troubleshoot :). Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/syslog` command(s): `dmesg`

Comment: I've edited these into the question :)

Comment: Sometimes I have the same issue. I think it is because the disk get errors. I would suggest you to boot from a live cd and do a system check and repair. Something like `sudo fsck.ext4 -cDfty -C 0 /dev/sda1` (change sda1 for your partition name and do it for every partition used in your system).

Comment: I really doubt it's a disk error, but thanks for the suggestion anyway. Windows works fine and I have installed Ubuntu countless times over the last year and the same problem has always been present.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a 17 second gap between these two lines in kernel log.

```
 ... [   13.402834] usbhid: USB HID core driver
 ... [   30.212288] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

hinting at a usbhid device initialization issue.

More large gaps are here:

```
 ... [   31.633630] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:3fff4000, size:c000
 ... [  322.243797] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
```

which seems to indicate an issue with fglrx (fireGL graphics) device initialization

and here:

```
 ... [   30.688474] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:3fff4000, size:c000 
 ... [   40.231355] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Again, a fireGL potential issue.

HTH

[edit: corrected based on insightful comment from ObsessiveFOSS]

Comment: Look carefully. The delays are caused by the entries *above* the gaps(The first of two in every quote), so this means that `usbhid` and `flgrx` are causing delays.

Comment: Thanks! you're correct, of course.  I corrected the above accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this will be an answer in progress and we'll try to fix all sources of unnecessary boot-up delay.

1. Your mouse/keyboard/touchpad (7 seconds)

   ```
   [    6.405954] EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
   [   13.450541] generic-usb 0003:1770:FF00.0001: timeout initializing reports
   ```

   What is that device? Can you try booting with mouse/kb unplugged, and plug it in once the login screen comes up?

(to be continued) :)

Comment: I'm afraid that, as it's a laptop, unplugging the touchpad and keyboard would be rather difficult :(