# Why does dpkg give me this parsing error?

Tags: installation, updates, libreoffice, dpkg

Any time I try to install software or updates, I get the following message (or a slight variation):

```
dpkg: error:
parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available'
near line 10650 package 'libreoffige-writev':
field name `Replaces>' must be followed by colon
```

I have no idea what it means, but it always insists that `` `Replaces>' `` be followed by a colon.

Comment: Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): `/var/lib/dpkg/available`

Comment: `bash: /var/lib/dpkg/available: Permission denied`

`sudo: /var/lib/dpkg/available: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

The following command should resolve your problem:

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem while trying to build a package:

```
$ dpkg --build ./mypackagefolder/
dpkg-deb: error: parsing file './mypackagefolder//DEBIAN/control' near line 13 package 'mypackage':
 field name `Bone' must be followed by colon
```

Turns out this happens if you have a line feed in the Description field of the DEBIAN/control file. The offending "field name" is then the first word on the new line. The fix is to make sure the Description is not force-wrapped. To write a multi-line Description, separate the one-line paragraphs with ' .' and make sure each one-line paragraph starts with a blank.