# Installation error during linux firmware installation

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

while trying to install linux firmware this error came up.:

```
After this operation, 8,249 kB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 2093 package 'x11-xkb-utils':
 field name `h��@' must be followed by colon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: Please provide the actual command and place you downloaded the package from if any and the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/157838/why-does-dpkg-give-me-this-parsing-error  is similar. Claims `sudo dpkg --clear-avail` should solve it