# How can I figure out why Suspend sometimes fails?

Tags: suspend

Something is causing suspend crash occasionally. When it does crash, the system freezes with a black screen and stays on, not suspending. This makes me have to hold the power button until the system shuts down.

One setting difference I have from most people is, I don't use the option that lets you suspend when the laptop lid is closed. So opening and closing the laptop lid has no actions. I like to press suspend manually.  Could this preference change be the cause?

How can I start looking for what's causing the crash, since the crash doesn't display errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, disabling the "suspend on lid close" function cannot affect manual suspend.

You would start by looking at the output of `dmesg` and the contents of `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog` for clues.

We can try to help if you share these with us. See this question for how:

> [How can I easily share the output of a command or a text file with others?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152371/how-can-i-easily-share-the-output-of-a-command-on-a-website/152372#152372)

Comment: Having a look at the mentioned log files is a good start. Suspend-specific log messages typically go into `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` though. (More details in my answer below.)

Comment: For anyone else searching, I found that pm-suspend.log was always empty but I found what I needed in the syslog on my system. I ran this command to get some details and found "codium" was causing my trouble... grep -A 35 'Freezing of tasks failed' /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 26):

I don't think the setting you mention is related.

## Trouble-shooting

Error messages relating to suspending are typically found in  `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` so have a look there.

## Typical cause

These problems are usually due to some process(es) stopping the system from being suspended.

Do

```
dmesg -T|grep Freez -A4
```

and look for these entries:

```
--
[sun mar  3 15:19:48 2013] Freezing user space processes ... 
[sun mar  3 15:20:08 2013] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.01 seconds (3 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[sun mar  3 15:20:08 2013] mount.nfs       D e8631aa0     0  5518   5517 0x00800004
[sun mar  3 15:20:08 2013]  e8631b10 00000086 f7bc0e00 e8631aa0 c1053cb4 c1809020 c192ee00 c192ee00
--
```

Check the time stamps to see which of the reported problems relate to your try to suspend. In this case, it is `mount.nfs` that is causing the problems.

## Suggested workaround

Have a script run automatically before suspending and have the script kill the offending process:

The user can provide scripts in the `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` directory. Those scripts will be run by the system at suspend and resume. The file name should start with an ordering number. 00-49 is used for user scripts. For details, see `man pm-suspend`.

The script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
(killall -9 mount.nfs; exit 0)
```

...with correpsonding entries for other processes that caused problems, if any.

Parenthesis and `exit 0` is a trick: if the process isn't found, `killall` will exit with en error exit code which will cancel the entire suspend. The parenthesis will make `killall` run in a sub-shell which will exit with exit code `0`, regardless of the `killall` exit code.

If you're having problems, check `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` since it will also log problems relating to running the scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`.

Comment: I also needed another line:  (killall -9 mount.nfs; exit 0) because sometimes it doesn't work with SIGUP only.

Comment: @Juanin: `-9` is better, I don't know why I had only `-1` in the first place, is edited now.

Comment: I wonder what percentage of the time the problem is a live network mount (as shown here).  That was my problem too -- but it was `sshfs` instead of `nfs`.

Comment: If there is more than one task refusing to freeze it could be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1676912

Comment: Is this method working in Ubuntu 18.04 also..??

Comment: Thank you! This solution was exactly what I needed. In my case was `mount.ntfs` that was causing me grief

Comment: @Ramesh-X My case was a process reading from a NFS mounted dir. NFS server was down. This was on 18.04, and `kill -9` was needed.

Comment: @Ramesh-X Yes, nothing has changed with the log `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` or with the ability to provide scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` so this should still work.