# Laptop doesn't suspend when closing lid or on manual trigger, then suspends after entering password

Tags: 18.04, suspend

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T480s.
And suspend no longer works.

1. When triggering suspend through the power options, it takes me to the login screen instead of suspending. After entering my password it goes to sleep.
2. Similarly, when closing the lid, the laptop stays powered on (fan spinning and LED is solid). I open the lid and I see the login screen. After entering my password it goes to sleep.

How can I find the cause of this issue?

Comment: A liittle bit fishing . `pkaction --verbose` many output please past it here https://paste.ubuntu.com/  and can you show `ps -ef | grep poli`

Comment: pkaction output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/58JNxvSS3R/ and the poli: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8FCyqrYSvC/

Comment: for gnome `sudo apt install policykit-1-gnome`  Log out and login again.  Control with `ps -ef | grep poli` if `polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` is running. Then try to suspend again.

Comment: installed it but, the process is not running unfortunately and suspend is still in the same state. tried reloggin and rebooting

Comment: `cp /etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop $HOME/.config/autostart`  open file in editor, search for string `NoDisplay=true` and set it to false, `NoDisplay=false` logout and login again, we need this agent running.

Comment: doesn't start with that either, I also tried to add the command `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` through the "startup applications" gui but it just disappears. also when running the command in the terminal it shows an error but doesn't exit: `(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:32707): GLib-CRITICAL **: 20:14:15.309: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find the cause of this issue?

Error messages relating to suspending are typically found in `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` so have a look there to begin with.

If you find errors like this:

```
[sun mar  3 15:19:48 2013] Freezing user space processes ... 
[sun mar  3 15:20:08 2013] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.01 seconds (3 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[sun mar  3 15:20:08 2013] mount.nfs       D e8631aa0     0  5518   5517 0x00800004
[sun mar  3 15:20:08 2013]  e8631b10 00000086 f7bc0e00 e8631aa0 c1053cb4 c1809020 c192ee00 c192ee00
```

...there's typically a process, in this case `mount.nfs`, that is stopping the system from suspending. If that is a case, I have provided a workaround here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/263510/77322

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I removed the password and then it worked fine. But again after I enabled the password, the same thing happened. I ended up re-installing my Ubuntu. Now it works perfectly fine. I hope this helps you...  ;)