# Why does HDMI sound stop working when not used?

Tags: sound, hdmi

When not used for a few hours the sound stops working on my HTPC. To get sound to work again I have to unplug the HDMI cable and plug it back in again

When this sound "outage" occurs, the HDMI device dissapears from the sound config output devices

I see the following in dmesg

```
[78534.010328] HDMI hot plug event: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0
[78534.010363] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0
[78558.948403] HDMI hot plug event: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78558.948429] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0
[78562.579047] HDMI hot plug event: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=0
[78562.579078] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78562.579992] HDMI hot plug event: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=1
[78562.580043] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78562.876030] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78563.176036] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78563.195139] HDMI hot plug event: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0
[78563.195169] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0
[78563.476030] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0
[78635.529493] HDMI hot plug event: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78635.529524] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0
[78641.330701] HDMI hot plug event: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=0
[78641.330733] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78641.331649] HDMI hot plug event: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=1
[78641.331668] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78641.628050] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78641.928037] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78642.228042] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78642.528039] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
[78642.828037] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=1 ELD_Valid=1
```

Comment: Can you re-establish the HDMI output by restarting pulseaudio (`pulseaudio -k`)?

Comment: nope, when I do this sound continues to not work and in the sound settings area HDMI is not listed as an output until I re-plug the HDMI cable. Sometimes I have to re-plug the cable a few times

Comment: Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/var/log/kern.log`, command(s): `dmesg`, `sudo lshw`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1080971/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1080973/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1080974/

Comment: the following gets the sound working again: pulseaudio -k ; service lightdm restart

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the latest driver from the AMD website after removing and purging FGLRX and it appears to be fixed

Time will tell but initial tests of switching TV off and on the problem does not occur