# Why has Gnome 3 reverted to classic (Gnome 2) look and feel?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

Not sure where to start with this one.

I've installed Gnome 3 by running `sudo apt-get install gnome` on my netbook, it all installed fine and ran fine didn't have any issues with it for a few weeks, then I turned on my netbook and logged in to be given the look and feel of Gnome 2.

I've cropped down the desktop in the image below.

[image: Gnome 3 Desktop]

Edit: Pastebinit as requested by izx

[kern.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1069591/)

[dmesg](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1069595/)

[sudo lshw](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1069597/)

Comment: may be your nvidia card driver have set to turn the composite extension off so that it can work fine.

Comment: @Amod The reason this was happening to me is because the nVidia drivers were installed but there is no nVidia card in the system. http://askubuntu.com/questions/158297/why-has-gnome-3-reverted-to-classic-gnome-2-look-and-feel#comment192562_158307

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's try the simple way to fix it first, because that looks like the Gnome3 *Classic* look (which is, yes, very similar to Gnome2)

1. Open a terminal, and type/paste:

   ```
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-shell
   ```
2. Logout
3. Click on the Ubuntu logo:

   [image]
4. Select the **Gnome** session, and click back:

   [image]
5. Login and see if you still get the Gnome2 look-and-feel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have done this and it didn't fix the issue. When I log in now I am still getting the Gnome3 Classic look and now my resolution is locked at 640x480.

Comment: You are falling back to 2D because your 3D is disabled, possibly because your graphics drivers are broken. Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/var/log/kern.log`, command(s): `dmesg`, `sudo lshw`

Comment: I've added the pastebinit links to the question.

Comment: @Nalum, why is the nvidia driver being loaded although you have no nvidia card? (see `dmesg` lines 919-921)

Comment: no idea why that is there. so if I uninstall that it should hopefully fix the issue?

Comment: Ran `sudo apt-get remove nvidia*` and then followed the steps in this http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-restore-default-video-drivers. Thanks for your help izx

Comment: @Nalum, very happy to know you solved your problem! Thanks for the link, I will add an edit to the answer about your particular situation and include it.