# Am I using Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why has Gnome 3 reverted to classic (Gnome 2) look and feel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158297/why-has-gnome-3-reverted-to-classic-gnome-2-look-and-feel)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 with gnome-classic instead of Unity. What I have is an "Applications, Places, ..." bar on the top and a taskbar on the bottom. Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but that looks like a Gnome 2 interface to me. As far as I've seen on the gnome site, Gnome 3 looks quite a bit different (icon bar on the left, contact list on the bottom, etc).

So I figured I had somehow gotten Gnome 2. But a check says it's Gnome 3:

```
$ gnome-session --version
gnome-session 3.6.0
```

So which one is it? :)

Comment: You are using gnome-session-fallback (check using `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`). You probably want gnome-shell.

Comment: Found the answer at:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/158297/why-has-gnome-3-reverted-to-classic-gnome-2-look-and-feel

Comment: Could you add your answer as an answer to your question? I'm not sure if this should be closes as a dupe or not, but if you have an answer, it is always better to actually add it with some description of what you did :D

Comment: 3.6? I just installed a fresh new Debian 7.7 and all I got was 3.4.1.0!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You running gnome-fallback edition of GNOME 3 that looks like GNOME 2. It has all the GNOME 3 softwares without the interactive shell.

So, `gnome-session --version` says the correct version.

Comment: oddly, this didn't print anything for me