# No public key GPG error when submitting quickly application

Tags: application-development, quickly

I try to submit my app with the command in the title, but the build failed:

Error message:
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY *****

***** is my key (don't know it is safe to share it)

If i run this command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ******
```

It is said my key isn't change (so don't need to add it again).

Any idea?

Comment: It's safe to share 8-digit key IDs. Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command(s): `gpg --list-keys`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your public key attached to your Launchpad profile.

- https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/ImportingYourPGPKey/