# Why is the firmware missing for my Belkin F5D7000 wireless adapter?

Tags: wireless, networking

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop and in the network setting it shows that the wireless card firmware is missing;
The network is belkin F5D7000 Wireless Network Adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears some versions of this adapter use a Broadcom chipset, in which case you can solve your problem by installing these packages from a terminal:

First run `sudo apt-get update`, and then run:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Then reboot, and see if it works.

If not, please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](https://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command(s): `dmesg` and `sudo lshw`