# Why doesn't 12.04 recognize plugged-in USB devices on startup?

Tags: 12.04, usb, hardware

When I log in, neither of my USB devices is seen. It's really driving me round the bend, I have USB keyboard and mouse connected. I have to unplug them then plug again and only then it works correctly.

Comment: how do you log in if they don't get recognised? can you post the output of `lsusb` to your initial question

Comment: He said un/re-plugging solves the problem. BTW, welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/var/log/kern.log`, command(s): `dmesg`, `lsusb`

Comment: I've got netbook.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with a wireless mouse that *sometimes* fails to boot up. Unplugging and re-plugging the receiver solves it. Someone once told me the receivers 'wear out'. Certainly it never used to happen, and the mouse concerned is getting old (i.e. about a year).

But IDK why a wired USB would fail in this way. (Or are we talking about a wireless k/b & mouse here?)