# 20 to 40 seconds pause during the boot on 12.04

Tags: boot

I've just installed new ASRock B75M-ITX Mainboard and fresh Ubuntu 12.04 on it.

During the boot, there is a 20 to 40 seconds pause when goa-daemon is starting (`/var/log/syslog`):

```
Jul  7 11:13:28 sirius goa[1933]: goa-daemon version 3.4.0 starting [main.c:112, main()]
Jul  7 11:13:51 sirius kernel: [  102.771893] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
```

Any ideas what is wrong and how should I proceed trouble-shooting this?

**EDIT:**
Thank you for the tip regarding ATA. I've found following in the logs:

```
Jul  8 10:54:20 sirius kernel: [    6.007532] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Jul  8 10:54:20 sirius kernel: [   10.648618] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
```

The problem vanished when I've reconnected the Intel G1 SSD from SATA3 to SATA2 connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source is most probably not `goa-daemon` but a delay/error in accessing your hard drive:

```
ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
```

*ata/frozen* typically appears after a drive fails to respond and the kernel has tried/re-tried the operation a few times, which may explain the 20-40 second wait.

To troubleshoot further, please pastebin the content or output of the following commands/files [(*instructions in this answer*)](https://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/syslog` and command(s): `dmesg`.