# Is it relatively safe to install kernel from "Canonical Kernel Team ppa" than "Mainline"

Tags: kernel, ppa

I already referred most of the questions stating **Upgrade from Mainline Builds or Compiling from latest source or PPA**  and also concluded that it  can cause breakage to Current stable installed system.

My question is regarding the **kernel** builds from [Canonical Kernel Team](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team) which i have subscribed in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit , states

> This is the core kernel team as hired by Canonical. Do not use this
>   team, use ubuntu-kernel-team instead.

My stable kernel states `3.2.0-27.42` from Ubuntu repository , also i consider **Canonical Kernel Team** to be Official ,currently urging me to Upgrade `3.2.0-27.43` , so from the Odd numbered and through the PPA description it is categorized as **Unstable**. From this ,it can be said next **stable release** would be `3.2.0-27.44`.

Is upgrading to `.43` version is stable enough to continue , since `.44` will be provide by Ubuntu itself based on `.43` version and so on.

Though i can't expect a lot of Changes ,but does it provide new **Improvements** or just **Bug Fixes** since it is just a preceding Release.

Also , apart from [Ubuntu mainline kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) , is [Canonical Kernel Team](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team) different. If so , in **what development or contribution terms**.

Is the **Ubuntu kernel** developed by Two different teams or [same team](http://reports.qa.ubuntu.com/reports/kernel-bugs/reports/).

**P.S.:**  Just noticed that `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` provides me upgrade to `.43` kernel , which normally requires `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade to newer kernel available , unless it normally provides message like *" Following packages were not upgraded..."* , is it an error or an exception to this Canonical Kernel PPA.

[image]

Heres the [apt-config dump](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1080963/)

Comment: Please accept the answer (if it answers your question), or let me know via comments if you need anything else :)

Comment: See the P.S : i added something.Please include that info if possible

Comment: See P.S. added at end of answer ;)

Comment: P.S.: I guess it does, see screenshot.

Comment: Can you pastebin the output of [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command(s): `apt-config dump`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The "core" Linux kernel is developed by Linus Torvalds and the "Linux Team" (lots and lots of developers, many of whom are employed by different companies).

  - Canonical Kernel Team consists of those core developers who are employed by Canonical
- The *Ubuntu* kernel team *does not work* on the core kernel, but instead customizes and builds them for Ubuntu, i.e. they turn Linux kernels into "Ubuntu kernels"

  - They *also* provide mainline (i.e. "core", uncustomized) kernel builds as a courtesy, for debugging purposes only.
- If you really want to try advanced kernel builds, the safest is the Ubuntu kernel-team's *pre-proposed* PPA (`ppa:kernel-ppa/pre-proposed`), which is *not* a mainline build and should soon find its way into a regular update.

  - The Canonical kernel team PPA is semi-private, and shouldn't really be subscribed to by normal users:

    ```
    This ppa is used for building pre-release and test kernels. 

    It IS NOT RECOMMENDED that you subscribe to this PPA.
    ```

Typically the kernels for an LTS release (and otherwise) will contain just bugfixes and minor improvements, no radical new features (e.g. btrfs, etc.).

P.S.: Based on your screenshot, this appears to be an exception for the Canonical Team ppa. After all it's meant for internal developer use only...

Comment: How does a PPA like this classifies itself a Exception to Apt-get.

Comment: That's a whole another question...on Debian control files.