# Why are both old and new optical drives not detected in Ubuntu or in Windows?

Tags: hardware, dvd, sata

I'm running 12.04LTS.

So I asked this same question on the ubuntuforums and was recommended to get a new drive. I've done that and still have the same problem. Here's the original (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11981491):

Hi there. So, let me preface this by saying that the drive in question was working. I used it to install 11.10 before upgrading to 12.04. I also used it to install the Win7 dual boot partition.

I'm running 12.04 64bit.

The drive is a Samsung SH-222. I can no longer access the drive in Windows or Ubuntu and I can't even use bootable CD/DVD even though it appears in my BIOS launch options. The drive is receiving power and opens, but if a disc is loaded I get no response (in either OS).

Here's fstab -  Quote:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass> proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation UUID=8f568673-81d3-40f0-aade-3f77fb65b151 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# /windows was on /dev/sda4 during installation UUID=79753E43529B03B9 /windows ntfs defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0 0
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation UUID=4d558b02-e348-4010-bbce-8a5ff8130c8a none swap sw 0 0
```

Here's `lspci`...

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09) 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) 
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04) 
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05) 
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05) 
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5) 
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5) 
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05) 
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05) 
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05) 
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05) 
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05) 
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

My main HDD is also SATA and is being read fine. I'm at a loss of why this is happening, not just in Ubuntu, but system wide.

Help would be greatly appreciated. This may have happened a week ago or a month ago, I'm really not sure. I so rarely use the DVD drive that I haven't had any reason to try, so I can't really pinpoint where/when it stopped working, sorry. If you need any additional information, I'll be more than happy to give it.

Thanks in advance.

So now, I have installed a brand new drive (same make/model) and am having the same outcome.

Here's the new lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change your **SATA CABLE** used to connect this drive and TRY. Better way to test it , exchange the SATA cables of Hard Drive and Cd/ Dvd Drive to make sure that SATA cable is working.

Comment: Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/var/log/kern.log`, command(s): `dmesg`, `sudo lshw -c disk`, `sudo lspci -vv`

Comment: dmesg: http://pastebin.com/yrCzpMA2

Comment: Seems I can only edit for 5 minutes and I hit enter by accident: 

dmesg: [link](http://pastebin.com/yrCzpMA2)
sudo lshw -c disk: [link](http://pastebin.com/KyTuXwn2)
sudp lspci -vv: [link](http://pastebin.com/jjyRBvr3)
output of /var/log/kern.log: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1080638/)

And thanks for the tip on the Ubuntu pastebin. Didn't see that until last

I'll work on changing the SATA cable also, but everything else has been tried. The cable is pretty new, so I hadn't gone that route since it's quite far to get SATA cables where I am, @tijybba

Comment: Then just try using the Cd/dvd's  SATA cable to boot into Hard drive only .

Comment: So I switched the cables, and both the DVDRW and the HDD are working, but I got a Disk I/O error initially. But it is up and running... I'm guessing something might be finicky with the cable? Here are the commands requested again.

dmesg: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1081130/
sudo lshw -c disk: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1081133/
sudp lspci -vv: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1081135/
/var/log/kern.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1081137/ <- ? Seems blank...

Comment: Here's also hwinfo --short: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1081156/
As you can see, the cd is there... Everything seems fine?

Answer (score 0):

You have already tried a different DVD drive. In addition, first try a different SATA cable. If the drive continues to fail, try a different SATA port on your motherboard. Finally, try using a different power connector from your power supply (one that's on a different cable, if possible).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried another port. The drive is getting power and opens/closes just fine. I'll try another SATA cable.