# Setting nomodeset (VESA graphics mode) through GRUB shell

Tags: boot, grub2, ati, nomodeset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set nomodeset for installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation)

I'm installing Ubuntu Desktop AMD64. I've previously done this on the same system with the Alternate iso install because it uses a text base installer. However, I'm having problems with that install so it was suggested to me that I try the regular Desktop Install.

The problem is that I'm using internal graphics that Ubuntu installer does not support. So I get an initial install prompt and then my monitor turns off as the install runs. The only thing I have access to is a GRUB shell. I can cat the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file. I think there are some options similar to "nomodeset" that can force the installer to use VESA graphics that will allow me to continue the install.

Does anyone know how/where to edit these options through GRUB?

(This question is related to [Dual Boot Installing Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7 (64) on a non UEFI system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160963/dual-boot-installing-ubuntu-12-04-with-windows-7-64-on-a-non-uefi-system))

Thanks

Comment: see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134029/cant-install-ubuntu-since-10-10