# Wireless card power management

Tags: 12.04, wireless, 64-bit, power-management

I have noticed that when my computer in plugged in, the wireless strength increases. I'm assuming this is to do with power management.

Is there a way to disable Wireless Power Management?

I have found a few blog posts that show hacks to disable this but what is best practice here? Should there not be an option via the power menu that lets you toggle this?

EDIT -- FILES AND LOGS AS REQUESTED

/var/log/kern.log

```
Jul 11 11:45:27 CoolBreeze kernel: [    6.528052] postgres (1308): /proc/1308/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/1308/oom_score_adj instead.
Jul 11 11:45:27 CoolBreeze kernel: [    6.532080] [fglrx] Gart USWC size:1280 M.
Jul 11 11:45:27 CoolBreeze kernel: [    6.532084] [fglrx] Gart cacheable size:508 M.
Jul 11 11:45:27 CoolBreeze kernel: [    6.532091] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
Jul 11 11:45:27 CoolBreeze kernel: [    6.532094] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f8fd000, size:403000 
Jul 11 11:45:27 CoolBreeze kernel: [    6.532098] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:3fff4000, size:c000 
Jul 11 11:45:38 CoolBreeze kernel: [   17.423743] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
Jul 11 11:46:37 CoolBreeze kernel: [   75.836426] warning: `proftpd' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
Jul 11 11:46:37 CoolBreeze kernel: [   75.884215] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (2922) terminated with status 1
Jul 11 11:54:25 CoolBreeze kernel: [  543.679614] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
```

dmesg

```
[    1.411959] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    1.412046] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
[    1.412054] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    1.412150] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input2
[    1.412765] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    1.412866] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
[    1.412874] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    1.412996] ACPI: Fan [FAN0] (off)
[    1.413068] ACPI: Fan [FAN1] (off)
[    1.419493] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
[    1.419498] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (27 C)
[    1.421913] thermal LNXTHERM:01: registered as thermal_zone1
[    1.421918] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (61 C)
[    1.421971] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for battery is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[    1.421986] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    1.422062] ERST: Table is not found!
[    1.422067] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
[    1.422158] isapnp: Scanning for PnP cards...
[    1.422242] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    1.434620] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    1.736355] Freeing initrd memory: 14352k freed
[    1.777846] isapnp: No Plug & Play device found
[    1.963650] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    1.967148] brd: module loaded
[    1.968866] loop: module loaded
[    1.969134] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
[    1.969154] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    1.969226] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.969277] ahci: SSS flag set, parallel bus scan disabled
[    1.969320] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 3 Gbps 0x23 impl SATA mode
[    1.969329] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq sntf stag pm led clo pio slum part ems sxs apst 
[    1.969338] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: setting latency timer to 64
[    1.983340] scsi0 : ahci
[    1.983515] scsi1 : ahci
[    1.983670] scsi2 : ahci
[    1.983829] scsi3 : ahci
[    1.983985] scsi4 : ahci
[    1.984145] scsi5 : ahci
[    1.984270] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf1005000 port 0xf1005100 irq 45
[    1.984277] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf1005000 port 0xf1005180 irq 45
[    1.984282] ata3: DUMMY
[    1.984285] ata4: DUMMY
[    1.984288] ata5: DUMMY
[    1.984292] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf1005000 port 0xf1005380 irq 45
[    1.985150] Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.985192] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    1.985196] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    1.985285] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    1.985472] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.985507] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    1.985534] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    1.985541] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.985626] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.985666] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: debug port 2
[    1.989663] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.989690] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: irq 16, io mem 0xf1005800
[    2.002183] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    2.002447] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.002455] hub 1-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    2.002607] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
[    2.002633] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    2.002639] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.002737] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    2.002775] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[    2.006780] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    2.006806] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: irq 23, io mem 0xf1005c00
[    2.022161] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    2.022401] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.022409] hub 2-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    2.022567] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    2.022599] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.022720] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
[    2.022813] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    2.035831] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    2.035844] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    2.036096] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.036710] rtc_cmos 00:07: RTC can wake from S4
[    2.036881] rtc_cmos 00:07: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    2.037143] rtc0: alarms up to one month, y3k, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    2.037503] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    2.037656] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    2.037725] EISA: Probing bus 0 at eisa.0
[    2.037729] EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[    2.037734] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[    2.037738] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[    2.037741] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
[    2.037745] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
[    2.037749] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
[    2.037753] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
[    2.037756] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
[    2.037760] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
[    2.037764] EISA: Detected 0 cards.
[    2.037782] cpufreq-nforce2: No nForce2 chipset.
[    2.038264] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    2.039015] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    2.039019] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    2.040061] TCP cubic registered
[    2.041438] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.043814] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.043823] Registering the dns_resolver key type
[    2.044290] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
[    2.044336] Using IPI No-Shortcut mode
[    2.045620] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    2.045644] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.073070]   Magic number: 4:976:796
[    2.073415] rtc_cmos 00:07: setting system clock to 2012-07-11 18:45:23 UTC (1342032323)
[    2.076654] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    2.076658] EDD information not available.
[    2.302111] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    2.302587] ata1.00: ATA-9: M4-CT128M4SSD2, 000F, max UDMA/100
[    2.302595] ata1.00: 250069680 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    2.303143] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    2.303453] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      M4-CT128M4SSD2   000F PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.303746] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.303920] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
[    2.304213] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.304225] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.304471] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.306818]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    2.308780] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.318162] Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 1595.999 MHz.
[    2.318169] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[    2.318178] Switching to clocksource tsc
[    2.450939] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.451121] hub 1-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    2.561786] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[    2.621757] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    2.636143] ata2.00: ATAPI: TSSTcorp DVD+/-RW TS-T633C, D800, max UDMA/100
[    2.636152] ata2.00: applying bridge limits
[    2.649711] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    2.653762] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            TSSTcorp DVD+-RW TS-T633C D800 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.661486] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    2.661494] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    2.661890] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    2.662156] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    2.694649] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.694840] hub 2-1:1.0: 8 ports detected
[    2.765823] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[    2.981454] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.982597] Freeing unused kernel memory: 740k freed
[    2.983523] Write protecting the kernel text: 5816k
[    2.983808] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 2376k
[    2.983811] NX-protecting the kernel data: 4424k
[    3.014594] udevd[127]: starting version 175
[    3.068925] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    3.068932] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    3.069714] sdhci-pci 0000:09:00.0: SDHCI controller found [1180:e822] (rev 1)
[    3.069742] sdhci-pci 0000:09:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    3.069786] sdhci-pci 0000:09:00.0: Will use DMA mode even though HW doesn't fully claim to support it.
[    3.069798] sdhci-pci 0000:09:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    3.069816] mmc0: no vmmc regulator found
[    3.069877] Registered led device: mmc0::
[    3.070946] mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:09:00.0] using DMA
[    3.071078] tg3.c:v3.121 (November 2, 2011)
[    3.071252] tg3 0000:0b:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[    3.071269] tg3 0000:0b:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    3.071403] firewire_ohci 0000:09:00.3: PCI INT D -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    3.071417] firewire_ohci 0000:09:00.3: setting latency timer to 64
[    3.078509] EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    3.078517] EXT4-fs (sda1): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    3.110417] tg3 0000:0b:00.0: eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM95784M) rev 5784100] (PCI Express) MAC address b8:ac:6f:71:02:a6
[    3.110425] tg3 0000:0b:00.0: eth0: attached PHY is 5784 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[0])
[    3.110431] tg3 0000:0b:00.0: eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
[    3.110436] tg3 0000:0b:00.0: eth0: dma_rwctrl[76180000] dma_mask[64-bit]
[    3.125492] firewire_ohci: Added fw-ohci device 0000:09:00.3, OHCI v1.10, 4 IR + 4 IT contexts, quirks 0x11
[    3.390124] EXT4-fs (sda1): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[    3.390135] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7078710
[    3.390232] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 2363071
[    3.390327] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7078711
[    3.390350] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7078709
[    3.390367] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7078708
[    3.390384] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7078707
[    3.390401] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7078706
[    3.390417] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7078705
[    3.390435] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7078551
[    3.390452] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7078523
[    3.390470] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7078520
[    3.390487] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7077901
[    3.390551] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 4063272
[    3.390562] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 4063266
[    3.390572] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 4063261
[    3.390582] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 4063256
[    3.390592] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 4063255
[    3.390602] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 2363072
[    3.390620] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 2360050
[    3.390698] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 5250064
[    3.390710] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 2365394
[    3.390728] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 2365390
[    3.390745] EXT4-fs (sda1): 22 orphan inodes deleted
[    3.390748] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
[    3.397636] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.624910] firewire_core: created device fw0: GUID 464fc000110e2661, S400
[    3.927467] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    3.929965] udevd[400]: starting version 175
[    3.933581] Adding 6278140k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:6278140k SS
[    3.945183] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    3.999389] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    4.016696] ite_cir: Auto-detected model: ITE8708 CIR transceiver
[    4.016702] ite_cir: Using model: ITE8708 CIR transceiver
[    4.016706] ite_cir: TX-capable: 1
[    4.016710] ite_cir: Sample period (ns): 8680
[    4.016713] ite_cir: TX carrier frequency (Hz): 38000
[    4.016716] ite_cir: TX duty cycle (%): 33
[    4.016719] ite_cir: RX low carrier frequency (Hz): 0
[    4.016722] ite_cir: RX high carrier frequency (Hz): 0
[    4.025684] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[    4.025691] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    4.027410] IR NEC protocol handler initialized
[    4.030250] lib80211: common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers
[    4.030257] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'NULL'
[    4.036024] IR RC5(x) protocol handler initialized
[    4.036092] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
[    4.036188] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.036307] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    4.036361] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    4.039006] acpi device:03: registered as cooling_device10
[    4.039164] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input5
[    4.039261] ACPI: Video Device [M86] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    4.049753] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    4.050201] wl 0000:05:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[    4.050215] wl 0000:05:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    4.052252] Registered IR keymap rc-rc6-mce
[    4.052432] input: ITE8708 CIR transceiver as /devices/virtual/rc/rc0/input6
[    4.054614] IR RC6 protocol handler initialized
[    4.054787] rc0: ITE8708 CIR transceiver as /devices/virtual/rc/rc0
[    4.054839] ite_cir: driver has been successfully loaded
[    4.057338] IR JVC protocol handler initialized
[    4.061553] IR Sony protocol handler initialized
[    4.066578] input: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (ite-cir) as /devices/virtual/input/input7
[    4.066724] IR MCE Keyboard/mouse protocol handler initialized
[    4.072580] lirc_dev: IR Remote Control driver registered, major 250 
[    4.073280] rc rc0: lirc_dev: driver ir-lirc-codec (ite-cir) registered at minor = 0
[    4.073286] IR LIRC bridge handler initialized
[    4.077849] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    4.079402] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2M (0c45:640f)
[    4.085492] EDAC MC: Ver: 2.1.0
[    4.087138] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'TKIP'
[    4.091027] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[    4.091733] snd_hda_intel 0000:02:00.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[    4.091826] snd_hda_intel 0000:02:00.1: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.091861] snd_hda_intel 0000:02:00.1: setting latency timer to 64
[    4.093115] EDAC i7core: Device not found: dev 00.0 PCI ID 8086:2c50
[    4.112448] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0
[    4.112612] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:02:00.1/sound/card1/input9
[    4.113311] type=1400 audit(1342032325.540:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=658 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.114501] type=1400 audit(1342032325.540:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=658 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.115253] type=1400 audit(1342032325.540:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=658 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.121870] input: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2M as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input10
[    4.122096] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    4.122100] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    4.128729] [fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 5840 MBytes.
[    4.129678] [fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 68c0 count: 1
[    4.131991] [fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0x2000, size: 0x100
[    4.132015] pci 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    4.132024] pci 0000:02:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    4.133712] [fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[    4.133747] [fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 8.96.4 [Mar 12 2012] with 1 minors
[    4.162666] eth1: Broadcom BCM4727 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 5.100.82.38
[    4.184133] device-mapper: multipath: version 1.3.0 loaded
[    4.196660] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
[    4.279897] input: Dell WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input11
[    4.292402] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    4.292449] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    4.292454] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.292459] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.292463] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.292473] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.296333] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    4.296342] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    4.296345] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    4.313586] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    4.316619] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.316625] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.383980] type=1400 audit(1342032325.812:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=938 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.385173] type=1400 audit(1342032325.812:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=938 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.425757] init: failsafe main process (898) killed by TERM signal
[    4.477052] type=1400 audit(1342032325.904:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1011 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.477592] type=1400 audit(1342032325.904:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=1010 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.478099] type=1400 audit(1342032325.904:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=1017 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.479233] type=1400 audit(1342032325.904:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=1014 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.510060] vesafb: mode is 1152x864x32, linelength=4608, pages=0
[    4.510065] vesafb: scrolling: redraw
[    4.510071] vesafb: Truecolor: size=0:8:8:8, shift=0:16:8:0
[    4.510084] mtrr: no more MTRRs available
[    4.513081] vesafb: framebuffer at 0xd0000000, mapped to 0xf9400000, using 3904k, total 3904k
[    4.515203] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 144x54
[    4.515278] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[    4.590743] tg3 0000:0b:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.702009] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    4.704409] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    4.978379] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.2, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xd04733/0xa40000/0xa0000
[    5.030104] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input12
[    5.045782] kvm: VM_EXIT_LOAD_IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL does not work properly. Using workaround
[    5.519573] [fglrx] ATIF platform detected with notification ID: 0x81
[    6.391466] fglrx_pci 0000:02:00.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.393137] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1305
[    6.393306] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1306
[    6.393472] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1307
[    6.393726] [fglrx] IRQ 49 Enabled
[    6.528052] postgres (1308): /proc/1308/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/1308/oom_score_adj instead.
[    6.532080] [fglrx] Gart USWC size:1280 M.
[    6.532084] [fglrx] Gart cacheable size:508 M.
[    6.532091] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
[    6.532094] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f8fd000, size:403000 
[    6.532098] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:3fff4000, size:c000 
[   17.423743] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
[   75.836426] warning: `proftpd' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
[   75.884215] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (2922) terminated with status 1
[  543.679614] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
kvm_intel             127560  0 
kvm                   359456  1 kvm_intel
joydev                 17393  0 
vesafb                 13516  1 
parport_pc             32114  0 
bnep                   17830  2 
ppdev                  12849  0 
rfcomm                 38139  0 
bluetooth             158438  10 bnep,rfcomm
dell_wmi               12601  0 
sparse_keymap          13658  1 dell_wmi
binfmt_misc            17292  1 
dell_laptop            17767  0 
dcdbas                 14098  1 dell_laptop
dm_multipath           22710  0 
fglrx                2909855  143 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31775  1 
psmouse                72919  0 
serio_raw              13027  0 
i7core_edac            23382  0 
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17275  0 
edac_core              46858  1 i7core_edac
uvcvideo               67203  0 
snd_hda_codec_idt      60251  1 
videodev               86588  1 uvcvideo
ir_lirc_codec          12739  0 
lirc_dev               18700  1 ir_lirc_codec
ir_mce_kbd_decoder     12681  0 
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
ir_sony_decoder        12462  0 
ir_jvc_decoder         12459  0 
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
ir_rc6_decoder         12459  0 
wl                   2646601  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ir_rc5_decoder         12459  0 
video                  19068  0 
snd_hda_intel          32765  5 
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
rc_rc6_mce             12454  0 
lib80211               14040  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
ir_nec_decoder         12459  0 
snd_pcm                80845  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
ite_cir                24743  0 
rc_core                21263  10 ir_lirc_codec,ir_mce_kbd_decoder,ir_sony_decoder,ir_jvc_decoder,ir_rc6_decoder,ir_rc5_decoder,rc_rc6_mce,ir_nec_decoder,ite_cir
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
wmi                    18744  1 dell_wmi
snd                    62064  20 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_timer
mac_hid                13077  0 
soundcore              14635  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
coretemp               13269  0 
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
tg3                   141369  0 
firewire_ohci          40172  0 
sdhci_pci              18324  0 
firewire_core          56906  1 firewire_ohci
sdhci                  28241  1 sdhci_pci
crc_itu_t              12627  1 firewire_core
```

lshw

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: 70:f1:a1:a9:54:31
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.38 ip=192.168.0.117 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:f0900000-f0903fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: b8:ac:6f:71:02:a6
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.121 firmware=sb v2.19 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:48 memory:f0d00000-f0d0ffff
```

Comment: Any such options depend on the model and driver of your card; there's no single one that works for all, so Ubuntu doesn't include it. But let's get your problem solved: please share the content or output of the following commands/files [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/var/log/kern.log`, command(s): `dmesg`, `sudo lshw -c network`, `lsmod`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit the following file by entering:

sudo gedit /etc/rc.local

add the lines to disable wlan0 wireless:
sleep 10 (this gives the wireless dongle/card time to to load, before executing the command below)
"iwconfig wlan0 power off"

important! make sure there is a line at the very end that reads:

"exit 0"

this will bypass any errors and allow the system to continue to boot.

you can add other startup commands here as well - very useful.

it should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sleep 10
iwconfig wlan0 power off
exit 0
```

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11254836&postcount=12

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few years ago, and I think this should still work: http://uselessuseofcat.com/?p=67

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you. Is this the best possible solution... ?

Comment: I've followed those instruction but im stuck where it says edit the file called wireless at /etc/pm/power.d/wireless. It doesnt seem to exist?

Comment: This answer did not work for me. The bottom two comments were the most relevant. This answer is relevant for older versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended practice is creating (as root) a file (say `block-powermanagement`) in `/etc/pm/config.d/` directory with the line `HOOK_BLACKLIST="$HOOK_BLACKLIST wireless"`.

```
echo HOOK_BLACKLIST=\"\$HOOK_BLACKLIST wireless\" | sudo tee /etc/pm/config.d/block-powermanagement
```

should do it.

Sources: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pm-utils#Disabling_a_hook and some others.