# Why does my laptop only show a cursor after closing and then opening the screen?

Tags: laptop, display

When i close my laptop screen and open it, the screen stays black, but i can see the cursor.  I can switch to the other ttys using ctrl+alt+F1-F6, so computer isn't l0cked out or unresponsive, the gui just doesn't show anythimg other than the cursor.  Does any one know the problem could be?

**Edit: log/command output**

- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35887513/dmesg.out
- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35887513/var-log-kern-log
- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35887513/var-log-syslog
- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35887513/xorg-0-log

Comment: Probably your graphics/display driver doesn't unsuspend properly. Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, command(s): `dmesg`

Comment: @izx Sorry it took so long.  Edited my question to include the requested log files and the output to that command.

Comment: Can you move the cursor? Can you try switching to a TTY and then back (with C-A-F7)? Is this a Lenovo/Thinkpad by any chance?

Comment: @izx I can move the cursor. I tried all ctrl+alt+F# combos.  This is a Lenovo Thinkpad X61 Tablet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the symptoms, and having Intel video, it sounds like you're hitting [bug 966744](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/966744): 
"[i965] Resume from suspend leaves me with black screen..."

Update: a fix has been found! :-)

It is in Quantal and working for.  For 12.04, it's in precise-proposed, as of now, 2012/10/10.  All reports from there are good, too.

---

Upstream Intel developers are working with Ubuntu devs and users, there.  You might be able to help by getting an xtrace.  There are instructions in a bug comment [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/966744/comments/226), but full disclosure, I couldn't get them to work.  Others did.

Here's an update, from the ubuntu-devel list (the end of [this email](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2012-September/001958.html)).

"For 966744, it seems a non-trivial mesa bug. Timo reported it upstream. Already present in precise, but doesn't seem to trigger as often as in quantal. Will need possibily some help from the unity team on that one to workaround it."

Here are the upstream [X bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43090), and [kernel bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50227) reports.  (Thanks to Launchpad's excellent bug linking.)

Comment: Well, I guess it's something I'll have to live with until they get it straightened out.

Comment: How do I get an xtrace?

Comment: I'll add a link for that.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and when I go to tty1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), log in, and run `startx` after logging in I get my full desktop back.

I'm not sure why/how it works but seems like a fairly good workaround.