# What's the command to install the build-essential package?

Tags: command-line, package-management, compiling

What's the command on 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 for installing the build-essential package and linux headers generic package?

Comment: Did you already try sudo apt-get install build-essential in a terminal? Please inform. This should work both in a 32 or 64 bit OS. Thank you

Comment: yes i tried but it gives error :unable to locate package build-essential. so please help reg this.

Comment: Check the answers given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486449/the-problem-of-using-sudo-apt-get-install-build-essentials Most of the people confuses "build-essential" with "build-essentials", please inform if this is not your case. Thank you

Comment: sudo apt-get update and than sudo apt-get install build-essential should work.

Comment: sudo apt-get update gives error unable to connect to 192.168.2.1:8081:

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments and linked question, try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

If this isn't working, there's another problem that needs to be solved first.

Comment: These commands are not working

Comment: What's the output?

Answer (score 0):

So essentially `sudo apt-get update` is not working and trows `unable to connect to 192.168.2.1:8081`. (If you had this for a long time, your PC will probably not have had any updates during this)

You could try to go to the software sources and change the server to the 'main server'. I'm not sure if that is the problem here tho.

Maybe read through this:
["Unable to connect" error with apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164169/unable-to-connect-error-with-apt-get)