# software center and update icon disappeared

Tags: 14.04, software-center, update-manager

When I am trying to reinstall the software center the following message is coming.
Command run:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Pl help

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install software-center`.

Comment: when I do that a lot errors and warning messages are displayed...and after reading every archive packages "unable to connect to the proxy" is displayed

Comment: Post the exact error message on [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the link in your question.

Comment: pl find the link on error while updating http://paste.ubuntu.com/9756866/

Comment: If you are behind proxy see here.http://askubuntu.com/questions/164169/unable-to-connect-error-with-apt-get