# Trying to install realtek drivers for ASUS USB-N13, encountering "Compile make driver error: 2"

Tags: wireless, realtek, make

I'm trying to put an ASUS USB-N13 wireless adapter in my desktop running Ubuntu 12.04. The details of my problem are identical to the one described in this question: [Connecting Asus USB-N13 Wireless Adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168627/connecting-asus-usb-n13-wireless-adapter). As such, I'm running through the exact steps laid out in the top-rated answer to that question. All was going well until I get to building the drivers. `sudo bash install.sh` produces the following output:

```
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
    rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405.tar.gz
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/autoconf_rtl8712_usb_linux.h
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/clean
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl8712_cmd.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/config
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/crypto/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/crypto/rtl871x_security.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/debug/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/debug/rtl871x_debug.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/eeprom/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/eeprom/rtl871x_eeprom.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/efuse/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/efuse/rtl8712_efuse.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/hal/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/hal/rtl8712/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/hal/rtl8712/hal_init.c
[...truncated for space...]
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/ioctl/rtl871x_ioctl_linux.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/ioctl/rtl871x_ioctl_query.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/ioctl/rtl871x_ioctl_rtl.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/ioctl/rtl871x_ioctl_set.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/Kconfig
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/led/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/led/rtl8712_led.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/Makefile
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/mlme/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/mlme/ieee80211.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/mlme/rtl871x_mlme.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/mp/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/mp/rtl871x_mp.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/mp/rtl871x_mp_ioctl.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_dep/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_dep/linux/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_dep/linux/cmd_linux.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_dep/linux/io_linux.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_intf/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_intf/linux/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_intf/linux/os_intfs.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_intf/linux/usb_intf.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/os_intf/osdep_service.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/pwrctrl/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/pwrctrl/rtl871x_pwrctrl.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/recv/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/recv/rtl8712_recv.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/recv/rtl871x_recv.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/rf/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/rf/rtl8712_rf.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/rf/rtl871x_rf.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/runwpa
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/sta_mgt/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/sta_mgt/rtl871x_sta_mgt.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/wlan0dhcp
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/wpa1.conf
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit/rtl8712_xmit.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit/rtl871x_xmit.c
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm .tmp_versions -fr ; rm Module.symvers -fr
cd cmd ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd crypto ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd debug ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd eeprom ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal/rtl8712 ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd io ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd ioctl ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd led ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd mlme ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd mp ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd os_intf ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd os_intf/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd pwrctrl ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd recv ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd rf ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd sta_mgt ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd xmit; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd efuse; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic/build M=/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.o
In file included from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:23:0:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/osdep_service.h:151:17: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
In file included from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_ht.h:25:0,
                 from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/drv_types.h:67,
                 from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:24:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h: In function ‘get_da’:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:350:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:350:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:353:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:353:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:356:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:356:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:359:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:359:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h: In function ‘get_sa’:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:374:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:374:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:377:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:377:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:380:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:380:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:383:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:383:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h: In function ‘get_hdr_bssid’:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:397:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:397:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:400:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:400:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:403:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:403:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
In file included from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/drv_types.h:70:0,
                 from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:24:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_cmd.h: At top level:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_cmd.h:107:25: error: field ‘event_tasklet’ has incomplete type
In file included from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/drv_types.h:72:0,
                 from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:24:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_xmit.h:355:24: error: field ‘xmit_tasklet’ has incomplete type
In file included from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/drv_types.h:73:0,
                 from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:24:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_recv.h:205:24: error: field ‘recv_tasklet’ has incomplete type
In file included from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/drv_types.h:73:0,
                 from /home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:24:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_recv.h: In function ‘rxmem_to_recvframe’:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_recv.h:435:30: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_recv.h:435:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c: In function ‘_init_cmd_priv’:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:93:75: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:101:60: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c: In function ‘_init_evt_priv’:
/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:135:59: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
make[2]: *** [/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/thinkpad20/Downloads/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

I'm not a superuser, only a hobbyist. I really just want this to work ~.~ so I can get on with my life. Sigh. Anyway, grumbling aside, I hope people can help.

Comment: As morgan (1 rep user, can't comment) said this is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1079671

Answer (score 0):

This applies to 14.04:

The easiest way around this, I found, was to downgrade the kernel to the precise kernel:
Go to 
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2-precise/
and download the packages

```
linux-headers-3.2.0-030200-generic_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_amd64.deb
linux-headers-3.2.0-030200_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_all.deb
linux-image-3.2.0-030200-generic_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_amd64.deb
```

You can do that with wget:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2-precise/linux-headers-3.2.0-030200-generic_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2-precise/linux-headers-3.2.0-030200_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.2-precise/linux-image-3.2.0-030200-generic_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_amd64.deb
```

Then install them:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.2.0-030200_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.2.0-030200-generic_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.2.0-030200-generic_3.2.0-030200.201201042035_amd64.deb
```

Then you need to reboot into the 3.4 kernel. You do that by selecting 
Advanced
and then selecting the 3.4 kernel in the boot menu of Grub. If it works you need to configure Grub to use that kernel.

I'm just doing this myself, so I may post a follow-up of how to...

Try [Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

EDIT: Try the kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.6-quantal/
It worked better for me, because I had a problem with sound with my headset with the earlier version.

@guntbert, why did you edit it to an even older version? 3.4 works, in fact probably better than 3.2. One doesn't even need to install another driver then.

Comment: Would I still have the option to switch between kernel 3.2 and my current kernel, or does doing this somehow remove the ability to boot with the original kernel? I have the same compilation issue. This adaptor is very slow, and I'm told if you install these drivers it will work faster.