# How do I get my Wireless Adapter to work for My own Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: wireless, drivers, asus

I have purchased the ASUS USB-N13 USB Wireless Adapter for my desktop computer running Ubuntu 12.04. It said it had Linux support, so I went with it. I found out from their customer support that it doesn't support Ubuntu, but it's not impossible to get it to work. I have tried looking up proper drivers and such to download.

I've gotten it to recognize my router, but it still won't connect. All these solutions I'm seeing seem to be just for specific computers and not a general fix, so can someone help me find a solution to this dilemma?

I have tried other solutions I find on here, but they don't work for my own computer. So please give this question a chance.

I've tried this one: [connecting asus usb n13 wireless-adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168627/connecting-asus-usb-n13-wireless-adapter)

But it fails at the third step in the terminal after downloading the drivers from Realtek. In step 3 of the terminal process it involves building the drivers, with the text

```
cd ~/Downloads/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.3_4369.20120622
```

but it just tells me "No such file or directory exists."

Also, at the beginning of the question, the asker said they put in

```
lsmod | grep rt
```

I tried that and got a different result than what they got.

Theirs:

```
parport_pc
rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common
rtlwifi
mac80211
cfg80211
parport
```

Mine:
    parport_pc             32114  0 
    parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp

I don't know how to further differentiate my problem from other questions, just that my computer's specs may be different than that of the computers used in these different questions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us which version of Ubuntu are you using. There are Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10 but there is no Ubuntu 12.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04. Sorry for the inconvenience. Forgot to check.

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate.  If those answers  don't fully address your question, please edit it to include why and flag this for reopening.  Thanks!

Comment: How do I flag for reopening?

Comment: If your question is the same, the fact that this answers don't work for you isn't a reason for reopening. This question should only be reopen if it's a different question. If you state clearly what you have tried and not I'll update that question to try to incorporate your problems.

Comment: Definitely tried this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/168627/connecting-asus-usb-n13-wireless-adapter

And all the other ones I find seem to be dead ends or lead me right back to that one.

Comment: Please provide details about everything you've tried and/or about why other questions and answers don't apply to your situation. Without that information, you're not asking something different, and no one would be able to know how to help you. Until you've given that information (by editing your question) this should remain closed; once you've provided details about *all* of this, then it should probably be reopened.

Comment: OK, I hope this recent edit helps explain the situation thoroughly.

Comment: So far it looks as though that wasn't enough...

Comment: OK, I posted my problem in the comments of the question it says I duplicated. Hopefully someone will see it there and be able to help me.