# Trouble with Asus N-13 USB wireless adapter

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb, asus

complete noob here. I've just installed 12.04 LTS on an old computer, a Dell Dimension E520, and I'm trying to get my Asus N-13 adapter to work properly. When I plug it in, it connects like it should and it works for 5-10 minutes, but then it randomly stops working and I need to take it out and plug it back it to make it start working again. It never actually says it's lost the connection, it just stops working. If it helps, the light on the adapter is lit constantly, and when the adapter was working properly on a different computer, it would blink on and off sporadically.

I followed the advice on this thread: [Connecting Asus USB-N13 Wireless Adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168627/connecting-asus-usb-n13-wireless-adapter)

I installed the drivers and got the output specified, but the problem is persisting after rebooting. Please help AskUbuntu.

Here's my `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:17ab ASUSTek Computer, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:2105 Dell Computer Corp. Model L100 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem on Ubuntu 12.04

I followed the instructions on the link you provided to build a new driver but I could still not get the Asus usb-N13 to work.

I ran lsmod in the terminal and noticed the driver module "rtl8192cu" wasn't loaded. This is the driver for revision b1 of the N13.

I added the module to the startup list using

> sudo gedit /etc/modules

I added the name of the driver module to the end of the list, in this case, rt8192cu, and saved.

After a reboot the module was loaded and all worked well!

Sorry in advance for perhaps not writing the best post, this is my first one ever.  I'm a construction worker, not a linux expert!  I was just so excited to get it working I wanted to share and maybe help someone else out!

I haven't tried this method on 12.10 or 13.04 so I don't know if it will apply, but I had the same problem when I tried to run 13.04 on a live disk.