# Installing .tgz driver for Asus USB-N13 Wifi adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers

I've recently bought a USB wifi adapter, and wanted to install the driver, it's in the form of a `.tgz` so I'm unsure how to do this

Here is the driver: http://www.asus.com/uk/Networking/USBN13/HelpDesk_Download/

Answer (score 2):

The .tgz is an archive. In most file managers you can just try to open the file and it will show its contents, and from there you can extract it to a folder. Otherwise at the command line you can use the following to extract all the contents. I do this in a folder called src (for 'source') in my home directory, but you can do it anywhere you like.

```
tar xvzf [filename]
```

I've downloaded the driver from the site you mentioned and had a look. So you start with Linux_2302.zip and that contains DPO_RT3070_LinuxSTA_V2.3.0.2_20100422.tgz, right?

If you have a look in the archive you will see a text file called README_STA_usb, which has instructions on how to install your driver.

EDIT: By the way, are you sure your USB adapter won't just plug and play? I've had a look at the README above and it is designed for old Linux kernels. It's possible that the newer Linux kernels which ship with the latest versions of Ubuntu might just support your hardware out of the box.

EDIT: There is already a post on installing the USB-N13 with one chipset on Askubuntu without having to follow the detailed instructions in the README. [Connecting Asus USB-N13 Wireless Adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168627/connecting-asus-usb-n13-wireless-adapter)

Comment: It works straight out of the box, but every 10 mins it suddenly stops working, so i wanted to update the driver to see if that helped. And the read me file made no sense whatsoever to me. :(

Comment: Yes the README is super technical, but it may not be necessary to do everything there. Have a look here and see if that helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/168627/connecting-asus-usb-n13-wireless-adapter

Comment: @Haddock the drivers offered on the Asus site are outdated and the drivers on the Realtek site in the linked answer are also a bit dated. It's possible that the in kernel driver is the latest and best maintained Linux driver for this device, which means you should probably get another adapter. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported is hopefully still up to date (last update from 2013 :( ).