# How to install WiFi Driver rtl8192?

Tags: drivers, wireless

I am new in Ubuntu and I don't known how to install my USB WiFi adapter driver!

My USB WiFi comes with a driver disk and there are 2 folders named "Linux" & "upload". Both folders contain `.zip` and `tar.gz` files. I have extracted them but I still can't install the driver.

How can I fix it so that I can access the internet?

Comment: Post the folder content using `ls` command

Comment: How to do that ? Can you teach me ?

Comment: With the device plugged in, open a terminal window with CTRL + t and enter `lsusb` and post the results.  There is a chance that the drivers that came with the adapter are too old to work

Comment: Open terminal, navigate to folder using `cd` command. Example: `cd path/to/folder` then do `ls`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting Asus USB-N13 Wireless Adapter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168627/connecting-asus-usb-n13-wireless-adapter)

Comment: Jeremy31 here is a pic of lsusb command https://s15.postimg.org/3killnmgb/IMG_20161201_121703.jpg

Comment: SuB I read that topic and it gives me error 2 so its not working for me

Comment: Liso check this is my result of ls  command https://s11.postimg.org/ojry2sqrn/IMG_20161201_122730.jpg

Answer (score 4):

You will need a connection to the internet to install

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

After a kernel update is installed, you will need to reinstall the driver

```
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Without internet, you can download https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/archive/master.zip on a computer with internet access and transfer it to the Ubuntu desktop.  Right click on the file and choose extract here.  Then in terminal

```
cd Desktop/rtl9182eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Comment: Well I can't access to internet without installing driver for my USB adapter

Comment: Post result for `uname -a` and I will see if I have that kernel to compile.

Comment: Here is the result @Jeremy31 https://s18.postimg.org/qsttr9yx5/IMG_20161201_134043.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried run the installer ? If not, then run following command :

```
cd Desktop/Linux/upload/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.4_8819.20130822_beta
./install.sh
```

I saw `readme.txt` file, have you read that ? Maybe there's official instruction to install the driver.

Comment: It gives me an error https://s17.postimg.org/7ydnubqpb/IMG_20161201_132507.jpg and yes I've read that text file but its not helping me

Comment: @Beno Never, ever, ever, post images of text.

Comment: Why? What's wrong ?