# Ordinary use. Is GFX memory the culprit? Problems with 128 MB GFX memory

Tags: performance

I have noticed when on my laptop using an external screen+laptop screen, the terminal gets corrupted and responds really slowly; several bug reports and questions here are having the same symptoms. The "terminal" is a window with *terminal* or *byobu*.

In the laptop I have a dedicated NVidia (It is a T60 laptop), 128 MB of memory.

Because of one of the comments on one of the bug reports I was able to check the amount of ram free on the GFX card, with one browser and one terminal the pressure on the card was at 119 out of 128 MB. (Gnome3). Starting more apps ment less free RAM.

I can't grade or evaluate the validity of the bug reports so I'm not linking any of them.  The search terms I used was "terminal sluggish corruption".

Is the graphics card available RAM the culprit here?

- lspci -nn: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1169472
- dmesg : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1169473

The desktop display spans 3360x1200.

I'm currently using Gnome3. I find that Unity displays the same erroneous behavior, while Unity2D does not.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the bug reports, it appears extremely unlikely that the video memory (graphics card RAM) has anything to do with this issue. On the other hand, the graphics card itself (particularly its driver) probably have everything to do with it.

The bug seems to especially manifest when an external monitor is being used with some models of mobile Nvidia cards. What is the resolution of your laptop screen and the external monitor? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Do you have this problem if you try Unity 2D instead of Unity?

Also, please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](https://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command(s): `lspci -nn`, `dmesg`

Comment: I'm using gnome3. lspci -nn:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/1169472/    
dmesg : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1169473/

Comment: Regular Unity exposes the sluggish/malformed behaviour. Unity2D does not.