# How do I handle "Firmware file X not found" stopping bootup?

Tags: 12.04, boot, upgrade, kernel, freeze

I recently upgraded my desktop mac to Precise and now can't get past the `Ubuntu 12.04` splash page.  The splash freezes with

```
[   19.931097] b32-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode16_mimo.fw" not found
[   19.9311126] b32-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version.  Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
```

written on it

This is when I choose 3.2.0-generic from the grub menu.  If I choose to load up older kernels, I still get the same thing.

How can I make my computer finish booting again?

I'm able to ssh into the machine and poke around, but the actual screen freezes at the splash.

The firmware error is now gone ,but I still can't get past the splash screen

[`dmesg`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1192845/)

[`cat kern.log`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1192849/)

Comment: Why are you using GDM instead of the default lightdm? Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/var/log/kern.log`, command(s): `dmesg`

Comment: I probably am using LightDM if that's the default.  I haven't kept up with all of ubuntu's "innovations" since I don't use Gnome/KDE, so I never see them.  I'll pastebin that stuff, but, as @turbo points out below, I should really open up another question since the b43 wireless problem wasn't the cause of the machine not booting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got the possibility to connect to the internet by cable - highly likely if you can ssh into your machine - run `jockey-text` and see if this helps.

If this doesn't solve the issue just download the firmware from [wireless.kernel.org](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware) and just manually extract/copy it to `/lib/firmware/b43/`. Use `scp` for copying. If you can install `b43-fwcutter` and run `b43-fwcutter -i` to see what device you're on (if you don't already know).

If both ways fail update your question with details. The [Ubuntu Wiki bcm43xx page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access) has some details to continue the debugging.

Comment: The advice at wireless.kernel.org to `apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` seemed to get rid of the b43 error.  But my machine is still hanging at the splash screen.  Thank you for helping me fix that error!  If nobody can get me past that, I guess you get the bounty and I'll set up another question asking "How do I get past the splash screen?"

Comment: Why don't you open another question with dmesg output and so on? Would have been strange if the WiFi had blocked all of the boot-up.

Comment: Okay, I've asked about [the general freeze](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186132/how-do-i-make-ubuntu-go-past-the-splash-screen).