# How do I make Ubuntu go past the splash screen?

Tags: 12.04, boot, upgrade, kernel

I recently upgraded my desktop mac to Precise and now can't get past the Ubuntu 12.04 splash page. The splash freezes with Ubuntu and the dots turning from white to orange forever.

This is when I choose 3.2.0-generic from the grub menu. If I choose to load up older kernels, I still get the same thing.

How can I make my computer finish booting again?

I'm able to ssh into the machine and poke around, but the actual screen freezes at the splash.

[`dmesg`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1192845/)

[`cat kern.log`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1192849/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right then the Desktop Manager tries to start before your NVidia card is setup properly. It is an Ubuntu 10.04 Bug with MacBooks - but could be same problem with your hardware.At least I would give it a try ...

According to the answers here you should try the following:

a) adding some more time for your NVidia card to load

OR

b) editing `editing /etc/init/gdm.conf and /etc/init/kdm.conf`

More details and what to change exactly and how you will find here:

[KDM Bug in Ubuntu with NVidia](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdebase-workspace/+bug/585930)

Comment: I tried adding the various incantations from the Bug link, but they didn't work.  Where would I tell my machine to 'sleep 2'?

Comment: Thats a really good question. Here I found a link on what files might be a good try to add the "sleep 2 && ... (and then start kdm)) to: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/kdm.1.html But as long as I have never done that before myself I could just suggest that you play around with some files in there. I for one would add it here: "/etc/kde4/kdm/Xstartup". But thats just a guess and please make sure that you have a boot-cd at hand so that you can set settings back if the system won boot anymore. (even better you make copies of the modified files beforehand.)