# How do I select Wireless radio portions in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless

Bear with me, to be honest I have no idea what Wireless radio portions are.... At my school, I was told my the user support that the wireless network in my dorm uses 801.11 A/B/G/N. For some reason, the wireless in my room doesn't work. However, other buildings use only A/B/G, they say. In any other building, my wireless works fine.

How do I tell my system to use the G portion only? (As requested by user support in the email I received).

Here are the various logs/output requested:

- [dmesg](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1171041/)
- [lshw -c network](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1171044/)
- [lsmod](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1171045/)

Answer (score 2):

All N-radios also support G. The difference is that N is faster; you may be having problems staying connected because your wireless card radio keeps trying to use a weaker N-signal instead of the stronger G-signal in some places.

Let's make this an answer in progress. Please pastebin the commands `dmesg`, `lshw -c network` and `lsmod`, and edit your question with the links. We'll go from there.

Comment: Never used Pastebin before, so I just posted a link to the paste in my edit.

Comment: Ryan, to make things more convenient, please see the instructions here to easily pastebin single commands/files and include the three links -- thanks!: Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command(s): `dmesg`, `lshw -c network` and `lsmod`

Comment: Did as instructed. It is now in the edit. Thanks for this link

Comment: Bump :P Just kidding

Comment: @RyanMcClure: so sorry, completely forgot about this. Thanks for the reminder. On it!

Comment: No worries, I just thought I'd bring this post up so that it can be answered for the future. :)