# Can't replace MDM Display Manager with LightDM!

Tags: lightdm, display-manager

I installed MDM, and found it's incompatible with my VGA hardware. After rebooting I see:

[image]

This screen **repeats**, even if I choose Yes or No

As I have access to the console (by pressing ALT+F2) I tried,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

which gave me:

[image]

Even if I choose **LightDM** nothing happens at the next reboot. The first screen comes back!

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i mdm
ii mdm                1.0.4-0~webupd8~precise        Gnome Display Mnager
ii mint-mdm-themes    1.0.5-0~webupd8~precise1       Linux Mint MDM Themes
```

I need LightDM login screen back!

Comment: Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command(s): `dpkg -l | grep -i mdm`

Comment: I add it. Please see above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the message is telling you is that **lightdm is already running** in the background. So, login to the console-session/terminal by pressing `Alt+F2`, or choose **Exit to console login** from the window below.

[image]

Now, **remove MDM**, using the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get purge mdm      
sudo dpkg -r mdm mint-mdm-themes
```

Set LightDM as default from this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Then reboot. MDM should be gone by now.

LightDM may start, but it's most likely to be in **low graphics mode**.

[image]

To fix this, you have to edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` as following:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

As you are unable to edit `lightdm.conf` through console-session, I may suggest using the **Ubuntu Live CD**.

(Using the live cd, enter `gksu nautilus` on terminal, then locate and open `/media/yourUBUNTUpartition/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` from Gedit... then you can do the editing!)

Considering that you haven't installed **unity-greeter**, download the package for Precise from [here](http://nc.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-greeter/unity-greeter_0.2.8-0ubuntu1_i386.deb), and place it on `/media/yourUBUNTUpartition/home/YourName`.

That's it! Get out from the live CD and get back on the Console Session. (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>).

Now install the **Unity-Greeter** file you downloaded before:

```
sudo dpkg -i **unity-greeter_0.2.8-0ubuntu1_i386.deb**
```

Finally start LightDM,

```
sudo service start lightdm
```

Comment: Um.... I already removed MDM, (but using **sudo apt-get remove mdm**) That's why it's not present on the 2nd screenshot..but I never removed mdm themes. Do you want me to remove gdm?

Comment: Yes remove gdm AND run `sudo apt-get purge gdm mdm\*`

Comment: Does the purge command need internet? Well, it will take some time for me to gain internet access...(Now I'm on a Windows machine) I reply you as soon as I do it. Thanks!

Comment: No, no internet access is needed for purging.

Comment: Great! Finally LightDM is back! Well, I ran into some other trouble while doing it.So I added that stuff too to your answer, if you don't mind. Thanks!