# remote syslog hogging cpu

Tags: 12.04, apache2, webserver

Currently my Ubuntu server is using 80 %(+/- 10%) of my CPU.  The time on the process is 454:26.38.  How do I troubleshoot this type of issue?

What could be causing this/how do I fix it?

Comment: Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command(s): `ps aux`

Comment: root@max:/var/log# ps aux                                                                           
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND                            
root         1  0.0  0.1   2732  1284 ?        Ss   Aug31   0:02 /sbin/init                         
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug31   0:00 [kthreadd]                         
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug31   0:07 [ksoftirqd/0]

Comment: root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug31   1:05 [kworker/0:0]                      
root@max:/var/log#   0.1   2764  1048 hvc0     R+   10:04   0:00 ps auxbin/apach

Answer (score 1):

I restarted apache and that seemed to have resolved my issue.  It may have been due to me renaming the log files.  I renamed them because they were getting very large.