# How can i get into GUI mode?

Tags: gui

installed ubuntu-12.04.3 server. After installing, i could see only terminal mode login. I Dont see the GUI mode scree. How could i login to GUI mode login? If you need more details please let me know.

Comment: you need to install `ubuntu-desktop` package using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Got following : Reading package lists ... Done Building dependency tree Reading State Information ... Done E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu Server is, by default and by design, a text-based system. Why would you want to use up 200MB of RAM on stuff that isn't serving web pages or running applications over the network? You wouldn't. It doesn't make sense.

However, if you installed this thinking you wanted to run servers from an Ubuntu Desktop machine, you can do that with the standard Ubuntu install (I run several servers from this desktop). It's all fairly modular.

Similarly you can install the standard desktop meta-package (`ubuntu-desktop`) into a Server install. As this is a new install you'll also need to update the package lists. You'll need an active internet connection for this to work.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you  don't have a wired connection and need to configure this for a wifi first... Well honestly, you'll be quicker just downloading the standard Desktop CD and reinstalling.

Comment: Still i am facing same issue, unable to locate ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: Done with sudo apt-get update But not able to proceed with your 2nd command sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop. says unable to locate ubuntu-desktop. Let me know if any details needed.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `sudo apt-get update` please? [See this for help if you're struggling](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335770/how-can-i-run-a-command-and-copy-its-output/335771#335771).

Comment: I am doing sudo apt-get update &> /home/user/test.txt and very soon i will paste those output. If its big size is thr any attachments option here?

Comment: when i do apt-get update i have some error like Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com etc etc Could not connect to http://us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 ...

Comment: This sounds like you don't have an internet connection from the computer. I'd go with what I say at the end and just reinstall from a Desktop CD. It's going to be easier than fighting a command line if you're new to this.

Comment: Thanks, Oli. But wher do i get Desktop CD? Is it software? download it and write on some my CD? Let me know.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Oli, Installed Desktop. But now, when i do copy files/folder from my laptop to Ubuntu(VM Ware) it copies and even memory reduced but I don't see those copied files there!!

Comment: omg saved my life here with that command! Thank you!