# HP Pavilion G6 temperatures raises until system shuts down, how to fix this?

Tags: 12.04, hp, temperature

I'm using HP Pavilion G6 laptop, and I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04, from now whenever I use Ubuntu my system heats up and unexpectedly shutdowns.

Comment: You sure the fans/heat sink are clean and working? This happens with a live system too? Have you tried 13.04?

Comment: Please append the output of `lspci -nn` to your question. [See how](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335770/how-can-i-run-a-command-and-copy-its-output).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the proprietary drivers or open source drivers.
To enable proprietary drivers: Software Sourcers > Additional Drivers tab > Select a proprietary driver and hit apply changes. See if this resolves your problem. It did in the case of my HP dv7-1285dx Laptop.