# Ubuntu gnome stuck on a gray screen after login unless reboot

Tags: boot, gnome, login

i recently switched to Ubuntu gnome, and i didn't use to have this problem before. When the laptop boots, it reaches the login and let me insert the password, but then stuck at a gray screen. But if force shutdown the laptop with the power button and then reboot it, after login it shows me the Desktop. Actually to access my desktop i have to boot, login, reboot and login. I don't know it it could be related, but i also switched to the intel graphic card and disabled the nvidia because the laptop wasn't working anymore.

Comment: Inspect `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/auth.log` for any cause. Pastebin they if you want to share with us.

Comment: @Redbob I have no one of the file you mentioned. anyway today it seems to work... i've already boot it and shutdown three times and is working properly so i don't know.. can it be just a problem that occurs sometimes? do i need to worry?

Comment: Those files you must read with sudo. `sudo cat /var/log/syslog` . Not good idea having to shutdown to solve any problem. Better search for real cause.

Comment: this should be the log of a session i did shut down. no that's too long it doesn't let me paste it

Comment: You can [pastebin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152371/how-can-i-easily-share-the-output-of-a-command-or-a-text-file-with-others) this file.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25684016/