# WLAN connection lost every 5 minutes RTL8188EUS Lubuntu 20.4

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I have installed (l)ubuntu 20.4 on a HP 250 G3 laptop.

Since the internal WLAN adapter (RT3290LE) has also problems in Windows, I am installed a USB WLAN adapter with RTL8188EUS. I believe that I have disabled the internal RT3290LE WLAN adapter, but I am not sure about it. How does one check this out?.

The signal strength with is great now, but at the moment I am losing connection every 1 to 5 minutes. It reconnects and it is possible to work with works, but is it quite annoying.

Similar issues were all for older versions of ubuntu and usually called for updating the WLAN driver. I imagine that the new driver was in the lubuntu distribution, so I don't think this will be the problem. I also switched off IV6 in the nm-manager (ignore). I also saw something about preventing the system from turning off the adapter to save energy, but I could not find anything particular for the RTL8188 adapter.

From what I have read, maybe this information is helpful:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/s8Z3mTNXRk/

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/69Q6x8t3QY/

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/69Q6x8t3QY/

Where to go from here?

Greetings,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we see that your router is set to use WEP encryption, proven to be the least effective and easiest to hack of any encryption method. You might just as well leave a list of all your passwords and banking details on a list taped to your front door!

Please stop now and make changes to your router:

WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Your wireless may be dropping because of power management; that is, the feature where the card partially powers down to save battery power during periods of inactivity and then, ideally, powers back up seamlessly when activity resumes. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Finally, the driver for the internal device is still active. Let’s fix it:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rt2800pci
echo “blacklist rt2800pci”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Comment: Checked Router  - authentication encryption is set to WPA2-PSK is set and type of encryption is AES (and not TKIP). Where did you see encryption set to WPE?

Comment: with your suggested "sudo iw reg get" I get DE. How did you see that this is not working?

Comment: made the changes to conf.d and black listed the rt2800pci. Since then, no more dropped connections. Whew!  Don't know which one was the solution but, what a relief. Thank you very much!

Comment: P.S. I like the way you put in the commands and output from the terminal. It is much better than pastebninit which I found here [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152371/how-can-i-easily-share-the-output-of-a-command-or-a-text-file-with-others)

Comment: How do you to that?

Comment: In your *iwconfig* link: Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open <---That strongly suggests WEP. My WPA2-AES machine says nothing at all about encryption. What does this tell you? `nmcli device wifi list` My network says: Infra  149   405 Mbit/s  72      ▂▄▆_  WPA2

Comment: To show commands in a code block, either highlight the text and click the code button **{}** or else simply indent four spaces.

Comment: 'nmcli device wifi list' gives  16 Mbit/s  99      ▂▄▆█  WPA2     That is great!